# Android Studio : include an other path in a c file

Tags: c, android-studio, cmake, include

I develop an application on Android Studio, and I use the code of a C project. The 2 codes needs to be the same.
I have a C file myfile.c located in myC/abc/ with this :

```
#include "lib/myheader.h"
```

But myheader.h is located in myC/lib/
So the only way I found is :

```
#include "../lib/myheader.h"
```

But I need to keep the same code. So I can't change the file.
Is it possible? Anyone have an idea?

I use CMake to add C code to my project.

Comment: You can always specify include path with cmake and proper compiler flags, normally *gcc* for android so `-I/include/path/` should work.

Comment: Can you precise or give your sources?  I want this solution just for this file.

Comment: Use `-I/<path_to>/myC` as a compiler option. You can set up your makefile to do this. Then it will find `lib/myheader.h` under there.

Comment: thank you I did it in my CMake file

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I add `include_directories(src/main/myC)` in my CMakeList.txt.